# The right way to redirect wordpress structure using .htaccess regex

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks, http-redirect

Hi i'm trying to add a redirect regex to my .htaccess that redirect

from `/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%.html` to `/%category%/%postname%/%post_id%/`

[Yaost helper](https://yoast.com/research/permalink-helper.php) gave me this

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([^/]+).html$ https://www.ruoaa.com/$3
```

**i'm not an expert but i think it doesn't match my structure**

Also the permalink is not an option migration from blogger to wordpress already done long ago and permalink won't do the trick and all the upper links are giving 404

Answer (score 4):

There is **no way** take make this change using regex in .htaccess.   To be able to redirect to the new URL you need the `%category%` and the `%post_id%` for each URL, neither of which are available in the old URL.   You can't use regular expressions to parse the old URL and redirect to the new URL because the information to do so isn't available to the regex.

To implement this change you will need a totally different approach like one of the following:

- Install a redirect plugin to WordPress such as one of the ones suggested in [How To Change A WordPress Permalink](https://wpengine.com/resources/wordpress-permalinks/).
- Create a list of all the URLs and create a mapping between the old and new URLs to redirect each individually.   For a long list, you would want to use something like [Apache's RewriteMap functionality](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html).
- Rewrite the old style URLs to a custom handler and program it to look up the new URLs from the WordPress database.

Comment: is there any plugin or regex that can create a condition like if "postname" exists redirect to it . i already use a plugin do this called "WP 404 Auto Redirect to Similar Post"  but weirdly it misses a lot it seem that it match more than "postname" and no settings to edit

Comment: [The plugin recommended in the article](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) says "Changed your permalink structure? You can migrate old permalinks simply by entering the old permalink structure. Multiple migrations are supported."  I've never used it myself, but that sounds promising.

Comment: If you can't find a plugin that works for you you'll have to take one of the other approaches.  Or take a step back and ask if it is really worth changing your permalinks.   (It probably isn't worth changing them for any SEO related reason.)

Comment: redirection plugin allow you to redirect links one by one , it doesn't redirect structures, it allow you to use regex and inject it in .htaccess , that's all .

changing back is not an option since it's a migration from Blogger to Wordpress, the damage already done years ago but i'm still getting these 404 errors and losing most of my backlinks , these plugins are not doing the job correctly .

Comment: The plugin *says* it can do more than that, but if you have found that it can't you will need to look into the other solutions.

Answer (score 3):

It matches the URL you are wanting to redirect *from*. However, the redirect target is incorrect, as it will redirect to `/%postname%`, not `/%category%/%postname%/%post_id%/`.

But therein lies a problem, it's not possible to redirect to `/%category%/%postname%/%post_id%/` using `.htaccess` since `%catgeory%` and `%post_id%` are not present in the source URL.

You will need to do this using a redirection plugin in WordPress itself, since only WP knows this information. WP would need to lookup the `%category%` and `%post_id%` from its database using `%year%`, `%monthnum%` and/or `%postname%`.

Comment: I have more than a thousand urls, redirect plugins are not helping they require doing it manually link by link or auto redirect randomly .

If i can match "postname" only in both the job would be done (few duplicates in postname are solvable problem )

Comment: @Mo.Ali "If i can match "postname" only in both the job would be done" - Well, as mentioned, that's what your rule currently does. It redirects from `/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%.html` to `/%postname%` (no trailing slash).

Comment: it doesn't place a wildcard for both /category/ or /id/  before and after postname so it doesn't give the required link i guess , something like  /%*%/%postname%/%*%/

Comment: @Mo.Ali That doesn't make sense - you can't have a "wildcard" in the target URL. The _category_ would need to be looked up from the _postname_ somehow (assuming it is unique). `.htaccess` is an Apache config file, it works entirely outside of WordPress - WordPress does not see the URL being requested if you implement a redirect in `.htaccess`.

Comment: A plugin called "WP 404 Auto Redirect to Similar Post" do it so it's possible , i don't know how , the problem that it miss say by 15-20 percent, if it match postname only it won't miss .